# How to turn off editing an object with NURBS

Tags: modeling, nurbs-surface

[image]

I'm trying to  edit my object in edit mode, but it is slowing down my computer. I figured out that I turned on nurbs, but I'm not sure how I did that. Now I can't turn off nurbs to edit my object without crashing my computer. What is the shortcut for turning off nurbs? Thanks!

Edit: I started editing the model with just polygonal geometry and now it's smoothed. So when I try to edit a point, I can move the point, but the geometry is averaged by all the other points around it making the geometry smoothed.

I solved it. In the modifiers I changed it from Catmull-Clark to simple.

Comment: Nurbs is a type of curve object, and as far as I know it cannot be turned on and off, except maybe through behavior emulation. What did the object start out as? A bezier curve?

Comment: I started editing the model with just polygonal geometry and now it's smoothed. So when I try to edit a point, I can move the point, but the geometry is averaged by all the other points around it making it smoothed.

Comment: You haven't turned on proportional editing by mistake have you? - White dot in a blue square in the middle of the header bar instead of grey when it's disabled.